# Updating Discord Bot Commands in Terminal

Tags: terminal, discord.js

I have created a discord bot and was able to get it up and running without a problem in the past. I remember that I had to run two different commands in the terminal to get the bot up and running with no problems. The first command was something to get the bot commands updated in discord and the second was to actually get the bot online using

```
node bot.js
```

I need help figuring out what the first command is to get the bot commands updated on discord's server. I have rewatched all the videos that I followed before, but I cannot for the life of me find out what that command is.

I have a command handler that I followed off of the discord.js website when I first created the bot. I get the following error when adding a new file to my commands folder

```
[WARNING] The command at C:Desktop\DiscordBot\commands\play.js
is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.
```

There was a command that I had to run before running bot.js that fixed this issue.

I tried using the following command

```
build bot.js
```

but that obviously didn't work and isn't even a command at all.

Answer (score -3):

this is what you need to know in order to update commands....but you're going to get downvoted if you don't post that you've shown you tried to find the answer yourself...

https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-deployment.html#global-commands

The guide (link above) walks you through the steps, for update.  you need to first register the new commands, every time you want to make a command syntax change.  Once you've registered the commands with discord, then you can re-run your bot and it will see the updated changes.  if you're doing this on a development server, it's best, because it's instantaneous.  If you're doing this for multiple servers, then you need to update with global commands and it can take Discord up to an hour to propagate.

Comment: I flagged this for [deletion](/help/deleted-answers) because it consists almost entirely of a link. A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is [useful without it](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259): add context around the link so others will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part in case the linked page is unavailable. If you [edit] this answer to add more once it is deleted, please flag it for moderator attention so that it can be un-deleted.